# fmt::format library "malfunctioning"?

Tags: c++, format, fmt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <fmt/core.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout<<"Expected: '       -10'\n      got:'"<<fmt::format("{:>10d}",-10)<<"'\n";
    cout<<"Expected: '-000000010'\n      got:'"<<fmt::format("{:>010d}",-10)<<"'\n";

    cout<<"Expected: '   -10.457'\n      got:'"<<fmt::format("{:>10.3f}",-10.456789)<<"'\n";
    cout<<"Expected: '-00010.457'\n      got:'"<<fmt::format("{:>010.3f}",-10.456789)<<"'\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The code above describes what I would expect as "useful" result from the format library.
Instead something different gets out!
It's just an error of the library or there is any relative reason to sustain the output.

The code is at: https://godbolt.org/z/YrxMr5x6x
and the output depends on the version of the library, even the last version "malfunctions" according to "my personal taste" (but I suppose you may share it).

Bellow some outputs:

```
Expected: '       -10'
      got:'       -10' 
Expected: '-000000010'
      got:'0000000-10' 
Expected: '   -10.457'
      got:'   -10.457' 
Expected: '-00010.457'
      got:'000-10.457'
```

The last version:

```
Expected: '       -10'
      got:'       -10'
Expected: '-000000010'
      got:'       -10'
Expected: '   -10.457'
      got:'   -10.457'
Expected: '-00010.457'
      got:'   -10.457'
```

Comment: No problems here : https://godbolt.org/z/asodq34Tz (except that your second and last  expectation is wrong... it will prefix -10 with 0 as you requested)

Comment: Sad that format specifier differ between fmt/std...

Comment: @PepijnKramer When we request to fill with 0s a fixed space the sign comes at the end (I am creating the numbers from right to left, so we write the last digit the previous one etc, if we request to fill with 0s the available space that should be done before the sign ( on the right of it ) the 0000-10 is totally useless, while the last option selected in the last version, does not differentiate between formats 10.3f and 010.3f . Moreover I didn't understood your comment, I connected to the link you said and library 9.1.0 gives the "unexpected" output, while 10.0.0 makes no diff on 10.3f 010.3f

Comment: The way I understand format prefixes to the left with 'characters' not numbers. But it is annoying the format changes from one version to another that's for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The `0` option has no effect when the align option (`<`, `>`, or `^`) is specified. Just remove `>` and you will see the desirable output.

This behavior is for compatibility with `std::format`.

[[format.string.std]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/format.string.std#8):

> The `0` option is valid for arithmetic types other than `charT` and `bool`, pointer types, or when an integer presentation type is specified.
> For formatting arguments that have a value other than an infinity or a NaN, this option pads the formatted argument by **inserting the `0` character *n* times** following the sign or base prefix indicators (if any) **where *n* is 0 if the *align* option is present** and is the padding width otherwise.

Comment: The logic says that if filling is requested, than the alignment is ineffective as fully filled fields are always aligned to the left, to the right, and to the centre. So < > ^ may just be ignored in that case but should not change the behaviour ... The compatibility with something that behaves unexpectedly is unexpected !!! ( thanks for the subtle explanation ).

Comment: It's less about compatibility with std::format and more about the fact that it doesn't make sense to mix 0 and alignment.